# Is there a more pythonic way of writing the following maximum-value function:

Tags: python

```
def greatest(values):
    value_generator = (v for k,v in values)
    max_value = max(value_generator)
    return (k for k,v in values if v == max_value)

sample_data = ( ('id1', 3), ('id2', 5), ('id3', 5) )
items = list( greatest(sample_data) ) # Should produce ['id2', 'id3']
```

MapReduce anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, according to my tests, your version of `greatest` is faster -- by a bit, anyway:

```
>>> def greatest_orig(values):
...     value_generator = (v for k,v in values)
...     max_value = max(value_generator)
...     return (k for k,v in values if v == max_value)
... 
>>> def greatest_max_key(values):
...     max_value = max(values, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
...     return (k for k,v in values if v == max_value)
... 
>>> sample_data = tuple(('id' + str(i), random.randrange(0, 1000)) for i in range(10000))
>>> list(greatest_orig(sample_data)) == list(greatest_max_key(sample_data))
True
>>> %timeit list(greatest_orig(sample_data))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(greatest_max_key(sample_data))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 ms per loop
```

Of course, if you don't like assigning your generator to a name, you can just pass the generator to max directly -- way more readable than `max(values, key=itemgetter(1))[1]`, IMHO:

```
>>> def greatest_max_iter(values):
...     max_value = max((v for k, v in values))
...     return (k for k, v in values if v == max_value)
...                                                
>>> list(greatest_orig(sample_data)) == list(greatest_max_iter(sample_data))
True
>>> %timeit list(greatest_max_iter(sample_data))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop
```

Python allows you to omit the outer parens when doing things like this:

```
>>> def greatest_max_iter(values):
...     max_value = max(v for k, v in values)
...     return (k for k, v in values if v == max_value)
...
```

But for reasons I don't understand, doing it that way is slightly slower:

```
>>> %timeit list(greatest_max_iter(sample_data))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop
```

These are true micro-optimizations, unlikely to matter much. But I think that readability favors `max(v for k, v in values)` or `max((v for k, v in values))` over `max(values, key=itemgetter(1))[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate max_value like this:

```
max_value = max(sample_data, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
```

As said in the comments you could also use itemgetter for the max() function key:

```
import operator 
max_value = max(sample_data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]
```

So your code would be (with itemgetter and returning a list directly):

```
import operator 
def greatest(values):
    max_value = max(values, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1]
    return [k for k,v in values if v == max_value]
```

Comment: This will only return one value.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, right this is just to substitute the OP max_value calculation. Edited to prevent misunderstandings

Answer (score 3):

The built-in [`max`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) function has an optional `key` parameter that can custom sort data.  Below it sorts on the second item in the data tuples and returns the maximum one:

```
>>> sample_data = ('id1',3),('id2',5),('id3',5)
>>> def greatest(values):
...   m = max(values,key=lambda n: n[1])[1]
...   return [k for k,v in values if v==m]
...
>>> greatest(sample_data)
['id2', 'id3']
```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(1)` is an equivalent and somewhat faster way of spelling `lambda n:n[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def greatest(values):
    m = max(values, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
    return [k for k,v in values if v == m]
```

And use it like this:

```
>>> sample_data = (('id1', 3), ('id2', 5), ('id3', 5))
>>> greatest(sample_data)
['id2', 'id3']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `map`

```
>>> sample_data = ( ('id1', 3), ('id2', 5), ('id3', 5) )
>>> max_value = max(sample_data, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], filter((lambda x: x[1]==max_value), sample_data))
['id2', 'id3']
```

Comment: +1 for the nice functional exercise. Not sure if more pythonic, however.